# TextEdit producing "egrep: parentheses not balanced" error

Tags: shell-script, osx, editors

I've written a small bash script for work: I'm trying to update a file automatically based on the metadata.

Overall, the script works fine, but anytime I save a new version I get the error:

> egrep: parentheses not balanced

If I rewrite the line that begins `HOSTEDDATE=`, using the exact same syntax, it works again. I suspect it has something to do with the quotation marks which seem to change in appearance (perfectly vertical when first typed, angled after being re-saved as a new version).

Since I'm using plain text in TextEdit, is this a known issue? Is there a workaround that doesn't involve me re-writing the same line over and over again?

The relevant portion of the code is below:

```
for PIURL in ${ARRAY[*]}
    do
    HOSTEDDATE=`cURL -s ${PIURL} | strings | egrep -o "CreationDate\(D:[0-9]{6}" | egrep -o "[0-9]{6}"`
    FILE=${PIURL##*/}
    NAME=${FILE%.*}

    #find local file and pull date
    LOCALDATE=`ls $NAME* | egrep -o "[0-9]{6}"`

        if [[ ${HOSTEDDATE} > ${LOCALDATE} ]]; then
        #move old file to "ARCHIVED"
        mv $NAME* ARCHIVED/

        #download PI file with required name
        cURL -L -o ${NAME}_${HOSTEDDATE}.pdf $PIURL

        #send e-mail with 
        mail -s "${NAME} has a new PI" emcampbell@smcm.edu <<< "${NAME}_${DATE} has been uploaded to Pulse"
        fi
done
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Likely to do with encoding – this may help: [Quotes problem in Mavericks (or TextEdit)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/120488/192433)

Comment: The answer (above) here doesn't specify this, but *smart quotes* can be disabled at application-level via `TextEdit` > `Preferences` > `Smart quotes (checkbox)` as well (or restricted to rich text format).

Comment: See my answer below for a comprehensive list of options to disable this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a side-effect of the `Smart quotes` feature in MacOS. To disable, apply:

`TextEdit` > `Preferences` > `Smart quotes` (*uncheck*)

[image]

Alternatively, to restrict `Smart quotes` to rich-text documents **only**, apply:

`TextEdit` > `Preferences` > `Smart quotes and dashes in rich text documents only` (*check*)

[image]

Lastly, if you want to disable `Smart quotes` system-wide, refer to: [Quotes problem in Mavericks (or TextEdit)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/120488/192433)

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like your text editor changes the standard ASCII quotes to some fancier quotes. The problem with them is that the shell doesn't consider anything but the ASCII quotes as quotes, so the behavior changes.

E.g. normal quotes:

```
$ echo "foo\(bar"
foo\(bar
```

vs. fancy quotes:

```
$ echo “foo\(bar”
“foo(bar”
```

In the first case, the quotes protect the backslash, and had that been `egrep`, the backslash would protect the left parenthesis. In the second case, the shell doesn't see any quotes, so it handles the backslash, which is gone when the command sees it, and `egrep` will take it as the start of a grouping construct.

The solution is to fix the editor to produce ASCII quotes, or to use one that doesn't insist on changing the quotes.

Comment: Looks like you’re correct about the quotation marks not being ASCII — Travis provided some further clarification about this being an issue starting with Mavericks and how to circumvent it.